# Dynamics AX 2012 SQL Extraction of Base Enum Values

Tags: sql, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a table, view, or procedure I can use to extract the values from a Base Enum using SQL (straight from the DB, not within X++)?  I was able to find an isolated few in the table SRSAnalysisEnums but not the enum I need in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to access the Enums from outside AX (for example in sql) you can add the missing enums to SRSAnalysisEnums by adding the containing table to a perspective and rebuilding the models

Tools->Reporting tools->Update models

It is described here
http://abraaxapta.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/missing-enums-in-srsanalysisenums.html

And an different AX2012-only way of doing it

http://abraaxapta.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/accessing-enum-labels-from-outside-ax.html

Hope this helps

Comment: This did the trick (2012 version).  I only had to modify the query to iterate through the enum indexes and stored the values in a temp table.

Comment: Another reference for 2012 would be: http://ioi.solutions/retrieving-label-from-enum-value-in-dynamics-ax-sql-db

Answer (score 4):

Looping over enums is dead easy:

```
static void EnumIteration(Args _args)
{
    DictEnum enum = new DictEnum(enumName2Id("TestEnum"));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < enum.values(); i++)
    {
        info(enum.index2Label(i));
    }    
}
```

Roll it on your own table.

Comment: This helped me checking if a string value matches one element of an enum. Comparing my string with all the labels of elements has a meaning in my scenario so this is great. Thanks Jan!

Answer (score 2):

SELECT A.ENUMITEMVALUE, A.ENUMITEMLABEL AS ENUMITEMNAME FROM [DBO].SRSANALYSISENUMS A WHERE A.ENUMNAME = 'LedgerPostingType' AND A.LANGUAGEID = 'en-us'

straight from SQL table